# Use switch statement to compare a string against an enum

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I'm making (my own version of)roulette with Java, and one of the types of bets a player can make is to choose the color that is going to be rolled. (Even is black, odd is red). Is there a way I can use a switch statement to compare a string against an enum?

```
private enum colors{red, black};
private String colorGuess;
private boolean colorVerify = false;
public void getColorGuess(){
do{
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
colorGuess = in.nextLine();
switch(colors){
case red:
    colorVerify = true;
    break;
case black:
    colorVerify = true;
    break;
default:
    System.out.println("Invalid color selection!");
    break;
}while(colorVerify = false);
```

This is what i'm trying to get but it's not letting me use the enum 'colors' in a switch statement.

Comment: false false false: `while(colorVerify = false)`!!!

Comment: I think he tries to say that it should be a == instead of a == in the last line and he is correct

Comment: Or, even better, `while(!colorVerify)`

Comment: while(colorVerify = false) wouldn't even compile because it does not return a boolean!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You must have an instance of an enum type (its *member*) on which you switch. You are trying to switch on the Enum class itself, which is a meaningless construct. So you probably need

```
colors col = colors.valueOf(colorGuess);
switch (col) ...
```

BTW the name should be `Colors`, not `colors` to respect the very important and non-optional Java naming convention.

Comment: and the cases must be enum class name qualified

Comment: No, the enum class name is implied.

Comment: @Bohemian: that is untrue actually; simply red and black will do in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Been using an unnecessary if/else if statement for this for a while

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you're right... I have had to qualify my cases in the past. just trying to remember why :/

Comment: @Bohemian Name collisions, perhaps? Or maybe using legacy non-enum constants (ints).

Comment: Caution, this will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if passed an invalid String, which OP is trying to handle.

Answer (score 7):

You can get an enum from a string with [`Enum.valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-).  Take care here, the other answers fail to mention that `Enum.valueOf()` will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if passed an string which isn't a valid member of the enum.

Be sure to properly format and indent your code, it helps us (and you!) read it and understand what's going on:

```
// note the capitalization, and the singular 'Color'
private enum Color {RED, BLACK}; 

// At least with the code provided, you don't need colorGuess or colorVerify to be
// instance variables, they can be local to the method.  Limiting the amount of
// time a variable lives for (its scope) is critical for quality, maintainable code

public Color getColorGuess() {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // this should be outside the while loop
  while(in.hasNextLine()) {
    // .toUpperCase() lets you type "red" or "RED" and still match
    String line = in.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    try {
      // Enum.valueOf() throws an exception if the input is not valid
      Color guess = Color.valueOf(line);

      switch(guess) {
        case RED:
          return guess; // return, rather than break, to exit the method
        case BLACK:
          return guess;
        // As long as your switch statement covers all cases in your enum, you
        // don't need a default: case, you'll never reach it
      }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      System.out.println("Invalid color selection!");
    }
  }
}
```

Note that we now return `guess` in both cases, which is somewhat redundant.  At least with the example code you provided, you don't actually need to track `colorVerify` at all, because the method will keep looping forever until a valid color is entered.  You could replace the whole `switch` statement in my method with simply `return guess;` as you know it's a valid guess as soon as `Color.valueOf()` returns a value.

In other words, you could clean your code up to:

```
public static Color getColorGuess() {
  try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    while(in.hasNextLine()) {
      try {
        return Color.valueOf(in.nextLine().toUpperCase());
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid color selection!");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that the method is `static` now, and uses a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block to close the `Scanner` once you're done with it.